# Measured time inconsistent on swapping measuring order

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, time, quicksort

I was trying to compare 3 sorting algorithm's speed -  quicksort, modified quicksort, python built-in sort.
So i make a loop that repeat 1000 times, generate a random list with 1000 numbers 1-1000.

my code:

```
import random as r
import time
def modquicksort(target):                                      
    P=len(target)-1               #modified quicksort, there is a chance that it is slower and I have no clue what I was doing
    e=0
    pivot=target[P]
    
    for i in range(len(target)-1):             #divide the list into, smaller, equal, and larger by pivot
        if target[0]<pivot:
            target.insert(P-e,target[0])
            del target[0]
            
        elif target[0]==pivot:
            target.insert(P,target[0])
            del target[0]
            e+=1
        else:
            target.append(target[0])
            del target[0]
            P-=1
            
    if 0<P-e-1:        #normal
        Lt= modquicksort(target[0:P-e])
    elif 0==P-e-1:     #when the "smaller" is a single element, saves one function recusive
        Lt= [target[0]]
    else:              #when the "smaller" has no element, would cause error if you do it as normal
        Lt=[]
        
    if P<len(target)-2:   
        Ut= modquicksort(target[P+1:len(target)])
    elif P==len(target)-1-1:
        Ut= [target[len(target)-1]]
    else:
        Ut= []

    Lt.extend(target[P-e:P+1])     #putting 3 parts together, target[P-e:P+1] is the "equal part"
    Lt.extend(Ut)

    return Lt

def quicksort(target):            #ordinary in-place-quicksort i think, if i did if correctly                                 
    P=len(target)-1               
    pivot=target[P]
    
    for i in range(len(target)-1):             
        if target[0]<pivot:
            target.insert(P,target[0])
            del target[0]

        else:
            target.append(target[0])
            del target[0]
            P-=1
            
    if 0<P-1:        
        Lt= quicksort(target[0:P])
    elif 0==P-1:     
        Lt= [target[0]]
    else:              
        Lt=[]
        
    if P<len(target)-2:   
        Ut= quicksort(target[P+1:len(target)])
    elif P==len(target)-2:
        Ut= [target[len(target)-1]]
    else:
        Ut= []

    Lt.append(target[P])     
    Lt.extend(Ut)

    return Lt

def randomlist(size=1000,min=0,max=1000):
    list=[]
    for i in range(size):
        list.append(r.randrange(min,max))
    return list

#battle time!

time1=0
time2=0
time3=0
n=1000    #1000 runs slower enough for me

thelist=[]
for i in range(n):
    thelist=randomlist()

    start2=time.time()
    sort2=quicksort(thelist)
    time2+=time.time()-start2
    
    sort3=thelist
    start3=time.time()
    sort3.sort()
    time3+=time.time()-start3

    start1=time.time()
    sort1=modquicksort(thelist)
    time1+=time.time()-start1

avg1=time1/n
avg2=time2/n
avg3=time3/n

print(f"modified quicksort process time(avg): {avg1} s")
print(f"normal quicksort process time(avg): {avg2} s")      
print(f"built-in sort process time(avg): {avg3} s")

print("test if they work:(print 10 first elements)")
print(f"modified quicksort {sort1[0:10]}")
print(f"normal quicksort {sort2[0:10]}")
print(f"built-in sort {sort3[0:10]}")
```

look at below specifically. If i swap these, the measured time will be different

```
start1=time.time()
sort1=modquicksort(thelist)
time1+=time.time()-start1

start2=time.time()
sort2=quicksort(thelist)
time2+=time.time()-start2
    
sort3=thelist
start3=time.time()
sort3.sort()
time3+=time.time()-start3
```

for example, this is the output of 1->2->3:

```
modified quicksort process time(avg): 0.00194879150390625 s
normal quicksort process time(avg): 0.0022293198108673095 s
built-in sort process time(avg): 6.503438949584961e-05 s
test if they work:(print 10 first elements)
modified quicksort [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7]
normal quicksort [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7]
built-in sort [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7]
```

however, if I make it 2->3->1:
it became

```
modified quicksort process time(avg): 0.053626694202423095 s
normal quicksort process time(avg): 0.001788553237915039 s
built-in sort process time(avg): 6.534552574157715e-05 s
test if they work:(print 10 first elements)
modified quicksort [0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 12]
normal quicksort [0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 12]
built-in sort [0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 12]
```

modified quicksort process time; 0.0019 to 0.0536

output of same sort1,sort2,sort3 order is consistent
but swapping them change the result, it shouldn't happen

I tried time.process_time() and time.perf_counter() instead of time.time(). It doesn't fix the issue. I was trying to make it show the correct time elapse. But the result wasn't even consistent right now.

edit:
I watch Mcoding's video and he said orders matters so i shuffle the order by

```
permuations=[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
for i in range(n):
    thelist=randomlist()
    order=permuations[r.randint(0,5)]
    for i in order:
        if i==1:
            start1=time.perf_counter()
            sort1=modquicksort(thelist)
            time1+=time.perf_counter()-start1
        
        if i==2:
            start2=time.perf_counter()
            sort2=quicksort(thelist)
            time2+=time.perf_counter()-start2
       
        if i==3:
            sort3=thelist
            start3=time.perf_counter()
            sort3.sort()
            time3+=time.perf_counter()-start3
```

and it works!
If you want to know the result of testing. My modified quicksort is generally slightly slower than normal quicksort. And python built-in sort is 100x faster idk how.(how does it sort so fast?)
Also if the number range of the list is less than 15% of the list length, my modified quicksort would be a lot faster.

I still have problem on how to make these type of test better and how to optimize sorting lol. Please tell me.

Comment: @rcgldr Ok, but i just learned python and wanted to do stuff there. I could move to C after I am familiar to Python. Right now I am trying to optimize as much as I could on python.

Comment: Since Python interprets lines of code when running, what should be a faster algorithm but takes more lines of code will be slower in Python. Note that Python's built in sort and library functions in general are compiled code, in many cases compiled from C. As you've found out, the compiled code can be 100x faster than Python code. I get search matches when I do a search for Python compilers, and maybe one or more of these are actual compilers, which would help.